# Row filtering with respect to intersection of 2 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame named **data_2010** with 3 columns **CountryName**, **IndicatorName** and **Value**.

For eg.

```
data_2010

    CountryName                IndicatorName                               Value
4839015 Arab World  Access to electricity (% of population)             8.434222e+01
4839016 Arab World  Access to electricity, rural (% of rural popul...   7.196990e+01
4839017 Arab World  Access to electricity, urban (% of urban popul...   9.382846e+01
4839018 Arab World  Access to non-solid fuel (% of population)          8.600367e+01
4839019 Arab World  Access to non-solid fuel, rural (% of rural po...   7.455260e+01
... ... ... ...
5026216 Zimbabwe    Urban population (% of total)                       3.319600e+01
5026217 Zimbabwe    Urban population growth (annual %)                  1.279630e+00
5026218 Zimbabwe    Use of IMF credit (DOD, current US$)                5.287290e+08
5026219 Zimbabwe    Vitamin A supplementation coverage rate (% of ...   4.930002e+01
5026220 Zimbabwe    Womens share of population ages 15+ living wi...    5.898546e+01
```

The problem is there are 247 Unique countries and 1299 Unique IndicatorNames and every country doesn't have the data for the all the indicators. I want the set of countries and Indicator names such that every country has the data of the same indicator names and vice versa

(Edit)

df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CountryName': ['USA', 'USA','USA','UAE', 'UAE', 'Saudi', 'Saudi', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe'],
                   'IndicatorName': ['elec', 'area', 'fuel', 'elec','fuel','fuel', 'population', 'elec', 'fuel', 'co2 emission'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})
```

Expected output for df:

```
CountryName      IndicatorName     value
     USA              elec           1
     USA              fuel           3
     UAE              elec           4
     UAE              fuel           5
   Zimbabve           elec           8
   Zimbabve           fuel           9
```

Solution not working for this case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'CountryName': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'UAE', 'UAE', 'Saudi', 'Saudi', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe', 'Spain'],
     'IndicatorName': ['elec', 'area', 'fuel', 'elec','fuel','fuel', 'population', 'elec', 'fuel', 'co2 emission','population'],
     'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
     })
```

Output got:

```
  CountryName   IndicatorName   value
0   Saudi            fuel         6
1   Saudi         population      7
2   UAE              elec         4
3   UAE              fuel         5
4   USA              elec         1
5   USA              fuel         3
6   Zimbabwe         elec         8
7   Zimbabwe         fuel         9
```

Output expected:

```
     CountryName    IndicatorName   value
   0    UAE              elec         4
   1    UAE              fuel         5
   2    USA              elec         1
   3    USA              fuel         3
   4    Zimbabwe         elec         8
   5    Zimbabwe         fuel         9
```

Though Saudi has 2 indicators but they're not common to the rest.
For eg if Saudi had 3 indicators like ['elec', 'fuel', credit] then Saudi would be added to the final df with elec and fuel.

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby IndicatorName, get the number of unique countries that have the indicator name, then filter your df to keep only the rows that have that indicator for > 1 country.

Nit:  your CountryName column is missing a comma between 'USA' 'UAE', fixed below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'CountryName': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'UAE', 'UAE', 'Saudi', 'Saudi', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe', 'Zimbabwe'],
     'IndicatorName': ['elec', 'area', 'fuel', 'elec','fuel','fuel', 'population', 'elec', 'fuel', 'co2 emission'],
     'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
     })

df_indicators = df.groupby('IndicatorName', as_index=False)['CountryName'].nunique()

df_indicators = df_indicators.rename(columns={'CountryName': 'CountryCount'})

df_indicators = df_indicators[df_indicators['CountryCount'] > 1]

# merge on only the indicator column, how='inner' - which is the default so no need to specify
#  to keep only those indicators that have a value for > 1 country
df2use = df.merge(df_indicators[['IndicatorName']], on=['IndicatorName'])
df2use = df2use.sort_values(by=['CountryName', 'IndicatorName'])
```

to get

```
  CountryName IndicatorName  value
5       Saudi          fuel      6
1         UAE          elec      4
4         UAE          fuel      5
0         USA          elec      1
3         USA          fuel      3
2    Zimbabwe          elec      8
6    Zimbabwe          fuel      9
```

Looks like you also want to exclude Saudi because it although it has fuel, it has only 1 common IndicatorName.  If so, you can use a similar process for countries rather than indicators, starting with only the countries and indicators that survived the first round of filtering, so after the code above use:

```
df_countries = df2use.groupby('CountryName', as_index=False)['IndicatorName'].nunique()
df_countries = df_countries.rename(columns={'IndicatorName': 'IndicatorCount'})

df_countries = df_countries[df_countries['IndicatorCount'] > 1]

df2use = df2use.merge(df_countries[['CountryName']], on=['CountryName'])
df2use = df2use.sort_values(by=['CountryName', 'IndicatorName'])
```

to get

```
  CountryName IndicatorName  value
0         UAE          elec      4
1         UAE          fuel      5
2         USA          elec      1
3         USA          fuel      3
4    Zimbabwe          elec      8
5    Zimbabwe          fuel      9
```

Comment: Hey this works, but I actually want the opposite of this. The result of this is 247(All) countries and the indicators common to them. I want 1299(all) IndicatorNames and the countries common to them since i want to find the correlation for between the indicators

Comment: Oh, I think I understand.  What would the final output look like?  For example, 1 row per unique indicator, with 1 column per country, and put the value (or null) in each cell?

Comment: Also, I don't necessarily have to keep one of the column lengths fixed, I want those number of countries for which a set of indicatorNames are common or vice versa

Comment: So, the count of how many countries have indicator x, and the count of how many indicators country x has ?  Could you post what your ideal output looks like?

Comment: yes i've posted the expected out for a df

Comment: That actually made no difference to the dataframe for some reason. Are you sure about the > 1 thing? The minimum country count for indicatorNames in my df is 73

Comment: Play with the example and code that I posted and see if the toy example works.  Then compare your real data.  Filter your real data with the same techniques and try to find any country with only 1 indicator, or any indicator with only 1 country.  If there aren't any, then your original data will stay the same.

Comment: I tried playing with the toy data and made some changes to it and it doesn't work with another case, Ive posted the output I got and the output I expect